# How to decide between Activity or Heartbeat (or DIY Rules?)

Tags: heartbeat

I wish to create a site with status updates, and thus I want people to see those status updates.... (I am looking at the Facebook Style Statuses / Statuses module.)

It seems that I need to use either Activity or Heartbeat modules to get a stream of activity. However they both do similar things. How do I choose between the two? Is there a comparison anywhere?

I've seen a lot of discussion comparing them back in 2009 and talking about creating a unified version. However that discussion doesn't take into account Drupal 7 and doesn't seem to have resulted in a clear winner.

Answer (score 4):

I am developing an SNS site and I chose Heartbeat.  I would choose Heartbeat again today for the following reasons:

- Heartbeat has a stable D7 release.  Activity hasn't had any commits in 32 weeks (as of March 24, 2012) and is still in dev; there is no stable release yet.
- [Acquia](http://www.acquia.com/) chose Heartbeat over Activity for Drupal Gardens.
- Heartbeat has rules integration.  This makes it very easy to customize to do what you want it to do, especially because you get access to tokens through the token module.  Activity lacks rules support.
- Heartbeat has solid internationalization support.  This was a requirement as my site is multilingual.

Comment: In researching my own question I found this which is a *similar* question - but not the same...[http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/user-activity-module]