# How to use 'session' to check path history of user

Tags: sessions

I want to keep a track of the pages user visited, I got to know i can do this with the help of session and hook_node_view. Being a beginner, i couldn't find any particular help on using session API, can anyone help?

Comment: You want to keep track of visited pages using only $_SESSION? How about a module? See here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/user-activity-moduleacc

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to track user visiting there are some modules ready for that like [user visits](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_visits) .

or if you want to do something and need to write a module for that then hook_node_view will fire when user is viewing a node . you can implement it like below :

```
function YOURMODULENAME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode)
{
   global $user; //user data is here
}
```

now you can do what you want with user.

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted. i know about hook_node_view(), how to implement $_SESSION in it or some other session tracking way.

Comment: I don't recommend you to deal with $_session . drupal has two functions _drupal_session_read and _drupal_session_write , but this two functions are for drupal internal uses , if you persist using $_session then you can install Rules Session Variable (https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_session_vars) which allow you to deal with session as variables but my sugesstion is to create your own database table and save logs there .